# Connection failure between services on kubernetes worker nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have Nodejs services which run on AWS EKS cluster. The cluster has two worker nodes. service connects with another service.

Problem is, sometimes when I re-create the deployment, service fails to connect with another service, where it runs on another worker node.

EX: service 1 runs on worker node 1, service 2 runs on worker node 2. if service 1 runs as service1:3001(internal DNS) and when service 2 tries to connect that service, it fails

What I did to solve this time to time,

**Solution 1:** Update AWS Control-Plane

```
eksctl utils update-kube-proxy --name acceptance --approve
eksctl utils update-aws-node --name acceptance --approve
eksctl utils update-coredns --name acceptance --approve
eksctl update cluster --name acceptance --approve
```

**Note:** `I did this once, when solution 2 and 3 did not work`

**Solution 2:** Delete coredns pods and let start themself.

```
kubectl delete po coredns-workernode-1 coredns-workernode-2,
```

** Note:** `I only do this if solution 3 does not work`

**Solution 3:** 
Restarted the service again after I re-create the deployment.

These are solutions that I did to solve this connection failure between services.

**Note:** This does not happen when services run on the same worker node.

**Moreinfo**:

> worker node AMI: ami-0b7127e7a2a38802a
>   EC2 Type: t2.medium
>   Kubernetes verson : 1.13.10

Seems those are temporary solutions and seems CoreDNS doesn't work properly. No more troubleshooting ideas to solve this permanently.

Comment: Hi, what does fail mean? does it timeout ?

Comment: (node:21) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RequestError: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND crm crm:3002

Comment: Like above,my service name is crm in this error

Comment: Can you try to reproducer it with curl `curl -v -k https://crm:3002` from different node ?  so we can be sure that its not configuration error

Comment: Do I need to add https for internal DNS?

Comment: nope, DNS resolver do not need protocols, it should be without http, https.

Comment: root@cron-scheduler-74b5d77bf6-49rtx:/usr/src/app# curl -v -k http://crm-proxy:3002
* Rebuilt URL to: http://crm-proxy:3002/
*   Trying 10.100.162.215...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to crm-proxy (10.100.162.215) port 3002 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: crm-proxy:3002
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< X-Powered-By: Express

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199565/discussion-between-suresh-vishnoi-and-sarasa-gunawardhana).

Comment: sometimes when re-create same service , its fails to connect

Comment: https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/issues/219 This is what happens to me